# Page displaying older image

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am facing some strange issue. My image control on razor page is showing the older image even after it's been replaced with a new image on Windows Azure storage server. But when F5 (refresh) button is pressed, it displays the new one.

Flow:

- Browse image
- Preview image in image control
- Press Save button to save the image to Windows Azure Blob(Container). it calls up Post "Edit" method to save the image
- Return URL of windows azure storage using web api
- Calls up "Edit" Page with URL in model

Here is snippet of razor page

**Edit.cshtml**

```
@model iSPYCMS.Models.iSPYAccount

<div class="form-group">
   @Html.Label("Venue Logo")
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Image.ImageFile, new { type = "file", id="file" })                                                                              
 </div>                              
 <div>
    <img src="@Model.Image.ImagePath" id="imgpreview" style="width:400px;height:200px"/>
  </div>

<script>

    function readURL(input) {
       if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#imgpreview').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }

  $("#file").change(function () {
    readURL(this);
  });
</script>
```

**Model Snippet**

```
public class iSPYAccount
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public iSPYImage Image { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")] 
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        //create the instance of DB Service           
        iSPYAccount ispyaccount = new iSPYAccount();
        //Web service call and get the URL of Image from windows storage
        // http://azurewebsites.mywebsite/1.jpg
        ispyaccount.Image.ImagePath = Helper.GetImagePath(image.Name);

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "None")] 
    public ActionResult Edit(iSPYAccount account)
    {
     if (account.Image.ImageFile != null)
     {
        account.Image.imageDataURL =  Helper.GetImageDataURL(account.Image.ImageFile);
        account.Image.fileextension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(account.Image.ImageFile.FileName);
        //save image to windows azure storage     
        imageapi.SaveImage(account.Image.imageDataURLaccount.Image.fileextension);
        return RedirectToAction("Edit");
     }
   }
```

Comment: Try to clear your browser cache.

Comment: This is not the solution! it happens to all browser and even if i access it from some other machines same issue occurs. I cant tell clients to clear their cache every time they need to replace the image?

Comment: does add a random querystring number to your ImagePath help? such as `ispyaccount.Image.ImagePath = Helper.GetImagePath(image.Name) + "?r=" + (new Random()).Next();`

Comment: Why would add this number? do you mean if i change the URL it can help ? so better i delete the existing image and upload new one with new URL?